# How To update columns for particular ids

Tags: updates, mysql-python

update particular columns for set of bulk ids.
ex:

```
+-------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+
| id    | name                      | companyname                      |
+-------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1     |   BABAK TAVAKOLI          | FIRE PROTECTION                  |
| 2     |   BRIAN CHRISTOPHER RISI  | CORPORATION SYSTEMS              |
| 3     |   CHRISTIAN DOMINIK NAVAR | BUILD INC                        |
| 4     |   CHRISTIAN DOMINIK NAVAR | UNITED INC                       |
| 5     |   GABRIEL ALVAREZ         | G A BUILD                        |
+-------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

In this table total record 1000, I want to update 1-250 columns particularly

```
UPDATE productsale SET companyname = '****' WHERE id = 1 to 250;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE productsale SET companyname = '****' WHERE id >= 1 AND id < 250

Answer (score 0):

You must use the keyword `BETWEEN` not `TO`, in the following form: `UPDATE productsale SET companyname = '****' WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 250`